# How to overlay an image on top of another image

Tags: swift, uikit

I am working on creating a small word guessing app for a school assignment in uikit and I have been trying to figure out a way to overlay an image that updates based on the amount of incorrect guesses left on top of another image. I've spent almost 2 1/2 hours checking and I could not find a single method that worked.

So far this is what I've tried

```
let bgimg = UIImage(named: "background") // The image used as a background
    let bgimgview = UIImageView(image: bgimg) // Create the view holding the image
    bgimgview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500) // The size of the background image

    let frontimg = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)") // The image in the foreground
    let frontimgview = UIImageView(image: frontimg) // Create the view holding the image
    frontimgview.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 50, height: 50) // The size and position of the front image

    bgimgview.addSubview(frontimgview) // Add the front image on top of the background
```

I commented this one out so that my code could work

```
let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "background")!
//        let topImage = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")!
//        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
//        let newSize = rect.size // set this to what you need
//        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
//
//        bottomImage.draw(in: rect)
//        topImage.draw(in: rect)
//
//        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
//        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
//    }
//
//    var backgroundImageButton: UIButton! {
//        backgroundImageButton.setBackgroundImage(newImage)
```

Comment: To me, it seems unusual to add a child view to a `UIImageView`.  I tend to think of `UIImageView` as a leaf in the View hierarchy tree.  Typically what I might do is create a single parent view for both the images, then add two `UIImageView`s as children and position them relative to one another in the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adjusting the `alpha` value of the foreground image view. Alpha controls the transparency of a view-- an alpha of 1.0 makes it opaque, a value of 0 is invisible, and values between 0 and 1 make a view more or less transparent. If you have the two image views aligned so that one covers the other, you can set the foreground image alpha to any value from 0 to 1 to adjust how transparent it is.